# Create button to browse folders and select a file in python

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I'm developing a python widget using tkinter where I need a button which will operate like any of the open button we see today. Basically I want it to help users to browse a file, select it and click ok. What i want is , as soon as the user clicks 'ok', it'll copy the file from that location and save it into a particular location in a particular name, which will be then used by rest of my widget.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the various widgets in [tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog).  They could be very useful.  Particularly, you might want `askopenfilename` which will pop up a dialog where you can browse for a particular file -- When the user hits `OK` it returns a filename which you can do whatever you want with.